# Get full resolution image url from reddit post with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I'm new to web development and recently picked up javascript. Right now, I'm trying to pull a random post from the top-10 posts on this multi-reddit [RSS feed of wallpapers](https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn+wallpaper+MinimalWallpaper+spaceporn/search.rss?q=1920%201080&sort=top&restrict_sr=on&t=week). The links in the RSS feed don't always lead directly to an image, but I noticed that if I mouse over the thumbnail of an image, the HoverZoom extension for Chrome is still able to determine the original resolution image that I want to get.

How could I do this using basic javascript commands?

Comment: So the link isn't in the RSS feed, and you want to know how to get it?

Comment: The link to the image is in the rss feed, but not always directly. Sometimes its a link to an imgur album, or a website thats displaying the image as part of its content. I need to get the original image directly and at full resolution, regardless of whether a direct link (e.g.: ending in .jpg) is in the rss.

Comment: "The link to the image is in the rss feed, but not always directly. Sometimes its a link to an imgur album..." I see that, but do you know how HoverZoom is doing what it does?  I could not find a link to source code and did not install it given the nasty warnings about spyware -- no idea if they're true, but not taking the chance if I have no reason.

Comment: Here is the source code. I've been looking through it myself (I just exported it from GoogleCode). https://github.com/doronz/hoverzoom